# How can we see the difference between RGB and sRGB spaces?

Tags: color-spaces

RGB and sRGB I found were said to be two color spaces the former adding some kind of a standard. There are a lot of details about what their difference actually is but how exactly can we spot or see a difference? (If my whole concept is wrong please correct me.)

Comment: Do you mean the difference between Adobe RGB and sRGB?

Comment: If you have a Mac, then you could always switch back and forth between the two profiles, in your display's color settings, and compare.  Otherwise, I see a lot of variables at play here and I'm not too sure of an easy way to see.  A lot will depend on how your monitor is calibrated.

Comment: Agree with AndrewH RGB is not a color space. It is a color model.

Comment: What's the difference between a color space and a color model?

Comment: Color Space - the actual space (or range) to describe colors (RGB, CMYK, LAB, and HSV are color spaces) 
---
Color Model - a model used to portray a color space within a set of constraints and used to ensure consistent translation and representation of colors using that color model.